# ¿Cómo comparar dos tablas de una base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo una base de datos SQL Server y tengo dos tablas digamos que se llama DB_One  y la otra DB_Two,  y con algunos campos iguales y otros no e igualmente con los valores en esos campos. Lo que necesito hacer es una comparación entre las dos tablas que me indique los registros que son iguales y los que no. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

- DB_One

  ```
  |-----------------|                  
  | id              |
  |-----------------|                               
  | nombre          |
  |-----------------|                          
  | num_transaccion |
  |-----------------|
  | región          |
  |-----------------|                 
  | fecha           |
  |-----------------|
  ```
- DB_Two

  ```
  |-------------|
  | id          |
  |-------------|
  | nombre      |
  |-------------|
  | transacción |
  |-------------|
  | zona        |
  |-------------|
  | fecha       |
  |-------------|
  ```

Comment: quieres comparar campos o registros?

Comment: quiero comparar registros

Answer (score 4):

Voy a tratar de responderte en el sentido más amplio tu pregunta acerca de "ver los registros iguales o distintos". Supongamos que tenemos esto:

```
CREATE TABLE #DB_One ( id INT, nombre VARCHAR(255), num_transaccion INT, region VARCHAR(15), fecha DATETIME )
CREATE TABLE #DB_Two ( id INT, nombre VARCHAR(255), transaccion INT, zona VARCHAR(15), fecha DATETIME )

INSERT #DB_One ( id, nombre, num_transaccion, region, fecha ) 
VALUES  (1, 'nombre1', 1, 'zona1', '20170101'),
        (2, 'nombre2', 2, 'zona2', '20170201'),
        (3, 'nombre2', 3, 'zona3', '20170301'),
        (5, 'nombre5', 5, 'zona5', '20170501')

INSERT #DB_Two ( id, nombre, transaccion, zona, fecha )
VALUES  (1, 'nombre1', 1, 'zona1', '20170101'),
        (2, null, 2, 'zona2', '20170201'),
        (3, 'nombre3', 3, 'zona3', '20170301'),
        (4, 'nombre4', 4, 'zona4', '20170401')
```

Para los registros iguales, es simple, serán aquellos que tengan el mismo id y los mismos datos:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM #DB_One T1
    INNER JOIN #DB_Two T2
        ON  T1.id = T2.id
    WHERE   ISNULL(T1.nombre,'NULL') = ISNULL(T2.nombre,'NULL')
        AND ISNULL(T1.num_transaccion,-1) = ISNULL(T2.transaccion,-1)
        AND ISNULL(T1.region,-1) = ISNULL(T2.zona,-1)
        AND ISNULL(T1.fecha, '19000101') = ISNULL(T2.fecha,'19000101')

+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | nombre  | num_transaccion | region | fecha                    | id   | nombre  | transaccion | zona  | fecha                    |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| 1,00 | nombre1 | 1,00            | zona1  | 01/01/2017 12:00:00 a.m. | 1,00 | nombre1 | 1,00        | zona1 | 01/01/2017 12:00:00 a.m. |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Como no tengo seguridad que algún campo no sea `NULL` a las comparaciones les agregamos un `ISNULL()`, tenemos que elegir eso sí un valor que no pueda darse en cada columna, esto por que simplemente hacer `NULL = NULL` retornará falso, por lo que dos campos en `NULL` no van a ser evaluados como iguales.

Los distintos, ¿cuales son?, básicamente aquellos cuyo id es el mismo pero alguno de los datos difiere.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM #DB_One T1
    INNER JOIN #DB_Two T2
        ON  T1.id = T2.id
    WHERE   ISNULL(T1.nombre,'NULL') <> ISNULL(T2.nombre,'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(T1.num_transaccion,-1) <> ISNULL(T2.transaccion,-1)
        OR ISNULL(T1.region,-1) <> ISNULL(T2.zona,-1)
        OR ISNULL(T1.fecha, '19000101') <> ISNULL(T2.fecha,'19000101')

+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | nombre  | num_transaccion | region | fecha                    | id   | nombre  | transaccion | zona  | fecha                    |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| 2,00 | nombre2 | 2,00            | zona2  | 01/02/2017 12:00:00 a.m. | 2,00 |         | 2,00        | zona2 | 01/02/2017 12:00:00 a.m. |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| 3,00 | nombre2 | 3,00            | zona3  | 01/03/2017 12:00:00 a.m. | 3,00 | nombre3 | 3,00        | zona3 | 01/03/2017 12:00:00 a.m. |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Ahora bien, si revisás el ejemplo hay dos casos que no hemos considerado como distintos, técnicamente no lo son, se trata del `id=5` que está en `#DB_One` pero no en `#DB_One` y el `id=4` que aparece exactamente al revés, pero puede haber ocasiones en que sea necesario considerarlos como "distintos", si ese fuera el caso deberíamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  T1.*, T2.*
    FROM #DB_One T1
    LEFT JOIN #DB_Two T2
        ON  T1.id = T2.id
    WHERE   T2.id IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT  T1.*, T2.*
    FROM #DB_Two T2
    LEFT JOIN #DB_One T1
        ON  T1.id = T2.id
    WHERE   T1.id IS NULL

+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | nombre  | num_transaccion | region | fecha                    | id   | nombre  | transaccion | zona  | fecha                    |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
|      |         |                 |        |                          | 4,00 | nombre4 | 4,00        | zona4 | 01/04/2017 12:00:00 a.m. |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
| 5,00 | nombre5 | 5,00            | zona5  | 01/05/2017 12:00:00 a.m. |      |         |             |       |                          |
+------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select t1.id as id_Tabla_one, t2.id as id_Tabla_Two
from tabla_one t1
left join tabla_two t2 on t2.nombre = t1.nombre and t2.transaccion = 
t1.num_transaccion and t2.zona = t1.region and t2.fecha = t1.fecha
```

Si id_Tabla_Two te da null es que no existe un registro igual en la tabla 1, de lo contrario tendrás el registro que coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Podes resolverlo a través del uso de los operadores SET

Para aquellos registros que sean iguales podes usar intersect

```
select * from #tabla1
intersect
select * from #tabla2
```

Para saber cuales son los registros que no son iguales podrías usar el except

```
select * from #tabla1
except
select * from #tabla2
```

Espero que se de ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No sé qué comparación quieras hacer, pero recuerda que las bases de datos son conjuntos, en este caso estamos haciendo una comparación exacta.

```
SELECT primero.id ,segundo.id
FROM DB_One primero
INNER JOIN DB_Two segundo on primero.id=segundo.id
```

Si deseas traer x columna, debes colocar el subnombre (primero o segundo).nombre de la columna

Comment: Gracias voy a internarlo

Answer (score 0):

`````
`SELECT *
```FROM Table t, TableCompare tc1, TableCompare tc2, Table3 t3
```WHERE 
    t.FKt1 = tc1.pk and
    tc2.FKt3 =tc1.FKt3 and 
    tc1.PkId<> tc2.PkId  and
    t3.PkCode=t3.PkCode

assuming:

````Table t have a FK from TableCompare. FKt1 is FK of TableCompare PK`
````TableCompare have a FK from Table3. FKt3 is FK of Table3 PKCode.`
`````